# how to update my sencha app from Extjs2 to Extjs3?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

i'm trying to update my sencha app from Extjs2.0 to ExtJS 3, but i'm finding a bit difficulty in it.

actually i developed that application in ExtJS2 but now i have to use the grid panel which is present in Extjs3.

so when i include the extjs3 in the current html file my whole app crashes please help....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Picker</title>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources\css\sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources\css\ext-all-css.css" type="text/css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>       

     <script type="text/javascript" src="src\Stocking.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="src\Datafile.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="src\index.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #286999;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the [Official Sencha migration guide](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_2_to_3_Migration_Guide) first.  From there, you should identify specific parts of your application that are breaking.  If it is a layout issue, start commenting out individual panels one at a time to find the problem.  Once you've identified the panel with the layout issue, start commenting out individual widgets that might be causing the issue.

You should also take advantage of your debugging tools such as Firebug.  Use the call stack navigator.  You may be able to use it to locate the specific control with the problem.

**EDIT: official guide is gone from the interwebs... try http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?70352-Upgrading-to-Ext-3**

Comment: i have done that but the problem is in using the extjs3 which is a new framework. i he=ave to use the Ext.Grid which is in EXTJS3 into my current application which is in EXTJS2 . . . . . . . .

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot work on converting it to use Ext.grid.GridPanel or something similar available in ExtJS 3.X?

Comment: Migration guide link is dead

Comment: I haven't been able to find a live link for that... I'm destined to get downvoted into oblivion

Answer (score 2):

Why are you including Sencha Touch and Ext JS on the same page?  If you're planning on trying to run an Ext JS GridPanel on a mobile site... you probably aren't going to have an optimal user experience.

Also, just FYI, Ext JS 3 is not new (current version is 3.3).  It came out about a year and a half ago, and Ext 4 is due to hit beta within the next couple of months.  Might want to consider holding off on a large migration effort to 3.x if possible.

Comment: the problem is, i want to use the datepicker in Extjs2 which has a good UI thatn that of the one in ext3, so i want to use that ui and at the same time i need to use the grid which is not present in extjs2 but present in extjs3.....so please help me regarding that issue.......... :-(

Comment: The same grid has been in Ext since 1.0.  I have no clue what you are talking about.